# Question regarding target space, one-to-one functions and onto

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If I am understanding this correctly. We know $p_1$ has the domain of $A \times B$, where the first parameter of $p_1$ is an element of $A$, $p_1(a,b)=a$ where $a$ is an element of $A$. Since $B$ is a non-empty set, there exists a $b$ in $B$. Therefore, for all $a$ in $A$, $p_1(a,b)=a$. So in answering this question the target space of $p_1$ is the image of $A$ and the target space of $p_2$ is the image of $B$? So, then how would I show if the function is one-to-one or onto?

Consider the Cartesian product $A \times B$, where $A, B$ are finite nonempty sets, each with cardinality greater than $1$. There are two functions with domain $A \times B$, called projections, with mapping rules $p_1 (a, b) = a$ and $p_2 (a, b) = b$. What is the target space of $p_1$? Of $p_2$? Are either of $p_1,p_2$ one-to-one? Onto?

Comment: "the target space of p1 is the image of A": what do you mean by "the image of A"? Sets don't have an image, but functions do

Comment: so the target space of p1 is an element a in A? and the target space of p2 is an element b in B?

Answer (score 0):

Some definitions to help you:

A function $f:A \to B$ is called $\text{one-to-one}$ or $\text{injective}$  if the function $f$ is injective if $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x = y$. In words, the function $f$ is injective if each distinct element of $A$ $(x,y \in A, x \ne y)$ gets mapped to a different element of $B$. If two distinct elements of $A$ get sent to the same element of $B$ under $f$, then $f$ is **not** injective (one-to-one).

A function $f:A \to B$ is called $\text{onto}$ or $\text{surjective}$ if for every element $b \in B$, we can find an element $a \in A$ such that $b=f(a)$. In words, for every element $b \in B$ in the codomain (or target space, as you call it) there is an element $a \in A$ in the domain that maps to $b$ under $f$. If we can't find such an $a$ for every element $b$ in the codomain $B$, then $f$ is **not** surjective (onto).

For your first function, $p_1:A \times B \to A$, $\quad (a,b) \mapsto a$, do the distinct arbitrary ordered pairs $(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2) \in A \times B$ map to the same element in $A$? (Note that "distinct" in this case means that $(a_1 \ne a_2,b_1 \ne b_2)$.  For every $a \in A$, can we find an ordered pair such that $f(a,b)=a$? You can apply the definitions directly here. For the function $p_2$, it's exactly the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still really confused. Is there another way you can please explain it.